# zram trimming by writing zero pages

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I'm using ZRAM as a backing block device for /tmp filesystem in the following manner:

```
echo 8000000000 > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mkfs.ext4 -O dir_nlink,extent,extra_isize,flex_bg,^has_journal,uninit_bg -m0 \
          -b 4096 -L "zram0" /dev/zram0
mount -o barrier=0,commit=240,noatime,nodev,nosuid /dev/zram0 /tmp
chmod aogu+rwx /tmp
```

It works out reasonably well for me - however, there is an issue here - when files are removed, they are not zero'ed, so the ZRAM does not remote the compressed pages. Obviously running

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/ZERO bs=1M count={free-space-some-rest}; rm /tmp/ZERO
```

clears it up in the ZRAM - it gets notified of zero-pages and shrinks the store.

How can I get ext4 to zero used pages on delete? Also, any other suggestions on how to optimize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enabling the `discard` mount option for an Ext4 filesystem and running a recent Linux kernel. This option is being used for SSDs mainly. At the same time it is being currently supported by [`zram`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/zram.txt) too.

Comment: I don't think it works - there is still some good amount of RAM trimmed when zeroing it forcibly - but perhaps it does, I guess more testing needs to be done.

Comment: One of the final comments in that thread had answered the question for me :)

Comment: @qdot Could you answer the question here at superuser.com as well?

Comment: @user239558, it seems to me that qdot was writing about comment with text "Any new features can now be added only after zram moves out of staging for which we are aiming kernel-3.8 release." that he found on the page at "https://code.google.com/archive/p/compcache/issues/98".

Answer (score 0):

Use fstrim command:
`fstrim -v /tmp`